# The upgrade procedure failed when testing iAPs...?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, in-app-purchase

When I try to test an in-app purchase I get the error "Please check your Internet connection and your App Store account information" as a pop up in my app. I am using a test account and I have transferred this to my device, still no solution.

WHAT I DO TO RECREATE THIS GLITCH:

1. Run my application on the simulator or on my device
2. Click on an iAP - any purchase works
3. Sign in using a test account
4. The pop up denies me from the iAP, reading "The upgrade procedure failed" followed by "Please check your Internet connection and your App Store account information".

   I've searched the Internet for hours on end with no success, does anyone know the cause/solution of this?

Comment: Why does the title say "FIXED"?

Comment: You are duplicating your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691190/the-upgrade-procedure-failed - don't do that. You may edit your question to make it more informative, but don't ask the same question as two separate questions.

Comment: Can you please check your banking information on itunesconnect.apple.com.

Have you added your bank account information?

"Agreements, Tax, and Banking" Setup your paid application account info.